# window application to webapplication

Tags: windows

In my window application when I login I open a new window there I want to display the webapplication that is like xxx.aspx in the same window. How can i write the code in window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

[WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

> Enables the user to navigate Web pages
>   inside your form.
>
> The WebBrowser control lets you host
>   Web pages and other browser-enabled
>   documents in your Windows Forms
>   applications. You can use the
>   WebBrowser control, for example, to
>   provide integrated HTML-based user
>   assistance or Web browsing
>   capabilities in your application.
>   Additionally, you can use the
>   WebBrowser control to add your
>   existing Web-based controls to your
>   Windows Forms client applications.

***Edit:***

Add a webbrowser control from your tool box to the form in which you need to show the web page.

and you can use the Navigate method

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

See

**[Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate.aspx)**

Comment: mr.phoenix can u tell me programmatic i not understand please

Comment: ya it is working. i have one more doubt i want to display one of my webapplication which is my localmachine (D:\\sasiweb\xxx) in that i want to display any one of the webform how it is possible thank u

Comment: i write like this

 webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:1058/Admin/Default.aspx");
and it is working.